# SpotBugs reports malicious code vulnerability - is it really vulnerable?

Tags: java, spotbugs

Consider the following example class.

```java
public class ListWrapper<T> {

  public ListWrapper(List<T> list) {
    this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
  }

  private final List<T> list;

  public List<T> getList() {
    return list; // EI_EXPOSE_REP reported here.
  }

}
```

SpotBugs reports the above noted line as vulnerable.

Callers of `getList()` cannot modify the list, therefore, the internal representation of `ListWrapper` instances. Is SpotBugs just not smart enough to identify that the list cannot be modified, or am I missing something?

I can change the class to make a copy of the list in the constructor and return an unmodifiable view of the list in the getter.

```java
public class ListWrapper<T> {
  
  public ListWrapper(List<T> list, Function<List<T>, List<T>> wrapper) {
    this.list = wrapper.apply(list);
  }

  private final List<T> list;

  public List<T> getList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
  }

}
```

But that is not my goal here. I want the list to be unmodifiable within the scope of `ListWrapper` instances, so I store it as an unmodifiable view in the constructor. It would be pointless to wrap it once again in the getter.

Maybe this is a bug. I noticed another strange behavior.

Something like the following will report `EI_EXPOSE_REP2`, as expected.

```java
public ListWrapper(List<T> list) {
  this.list = list; // EI_EXPOSE_REP2 reported here.
}
```

Not for the following.

```java
public ListWrapper(Supplier<List<T>> listSupplier) {
  this.list = listSupplier.get();
}
```

But with the above, there's nothing stopping someone from doing something like this.

```java
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
final ListWrapper<Integer> listWrapper = new ListWrapper<>(() -> list);
```

Comment: It's just not smart enough.

Comment: how should it know that the list is unmodifiable? It is vulnerable, list can easily be replaced using reflection for example (addressing only the 1st question/part)

Comment: @user16320675 One could say the same about the getter. The method could be intercepted to return the list itself, not wrapped in an unmodifiable view.

Comment: so? since that can be done, exposing the list is secure?

Comment: I put your code into IntelliJ and ran the built-in code analyzer (Code > Inspect Code) and it didn't flag any issues. It does seem like overly cautious behavior on the part of SpotBugs. I didn't find any useful info [in their docs](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#ei2-may-expose-internal-representation-by-incorporating-reference-to-mutable-object-ei-expose-rep2) either.

Comment: FYI, I reported the false positive: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/2083.